# Retrieving specific values in Multimap

Tags: java, guava

I'm using a Multimap that has two values per key. Below is the code I'm using to get each value separately:

The first bit of code gets the first object value:

```
for(Object object : map.get(object))
{
    return object
}
```

Then, I'm using another method to retrieve the other value. This method takes the first object as an argument:

```
for(Object object : team.get(object))
{
    if(object != initialObject)
    {
        return object;
    }
}
```

This seems like a 'hackish' way of doing things, so is there any way for me to get the values more easily?

Comment: Just a note: Whenever possible (which should be most of the time), you should use the `ListMultimap` or `SetMultimap` type in your code, not the `Multimap` type itself (kind of like you generally want to use `List` or `Set`, not `Collection`). It sounds like you should almost certainly be using `ListMultimap` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Collection<Object> values = map.get(key);
checkState(values.size() == 2, String.format("Found %d values for key %s", values.size(), key));

return values.iterator().next(); // to get the first

Iterator<Object> it = values.iterator();
it.next(); // move the pointer to the second object
return it.next(); // get the second object
```

Comment: I might be mistaken but I think you've got extra nexts in there (values.iterator() should point to first element)

Comment: @Wug: `values.iterator()` will point to the first object, but to access the pointed object one needs to call `next()`, which will return the pointed object and advance the iterator.

Comment: I'm able to iterate to the first element, but I cannot iterate to the next element as I'm not able to to add another next().

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Guava, `Iterables#get` is probably what you want - it returns the Nth item from any iterable, example:

```
Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

// and to return value from position:
return Iterables.get(myMultimap.get(key), position);
```

If you're using a `ListMultimap` then it behaves very much like a map to a List so you can directly call `get(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

for getting all the values for the same key the most easiest way to do it will be :

```
    Iterator iterator = multimap.get(key).iterator();
    System.out.println("first element: " + iterator.next());
    System.out.println("second element: " + iterator.next());
    System.out.println("third element: " + iterator.next());
```

And so on

**another option** if you want to get all the elements without know how much elements there

```
  Iterator iterator = multimap.get(key).iterator();
   int index=1;
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(index +" element: " + iterator.next()); 
     index++;
        }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.