# Iterating through Multimap (Guava)

Tags: java, android, collections, multimap

I have a Multimap which saves custom objects multiple times (Places and Events) under the key values of "place" and "event", within those objects I have the place name and the event name (getters). How can I access these values when iterating through the Multimap.

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
Collection<Object> values = map.get(key);
checkState(values.size() == 2, String.format("Found %d values for key %s", values.size(), key));

return values.iterator().next(); // to get the first

Iterator<Object> it = values.iterator();
it.next(); // move the pointer to the second object
return it.next(); // get the second object
```

Check - [retrieving-specific-values-in-multimap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852535/retrieving-specific-values-in-multimap).